# How to put updating data in the Bash command prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

I am trying to make a prompt that would show the current battery percentage, however if I have my code for setting `PS1` in `.bashrc` the way that it's written then it only checks the data once when the interactive shell is initialized on opening a new instance of a terminal emulator. This requires me to reload `.bashrc` if  I want the data to update. I am still pretty new to unix-like operating systems, so it's possible and even probable that I'm missing something trivial. Perhaps I should create a daemon that updates the prompt?

This is not my whole code for prompt, but it's the relevant bit with the changing data.

```bsh
PS1="`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep "percentage:" | awk '$1 == "percentage:" {print $2}'`$ "
```

Comment: The answer may differ depending on the shell, but you've listed several.  Which do you want an answer for?

Comment: preferably every shell that you know, but if I were to choose only one then BASH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a good way to actively update the value, but you can update it whenever there's activity at the shell (e.g., when you press Enter) using `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```bsh
update_ps1() {
    PS1="$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep "percentage:" | awk '$1 == "percentage:" {print $2}')$ "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_ps1
```

With that, I've added a bash function named `update_ps1` that, when executed, will update the `PS1` variable.  Next, I set the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to the name of that function.  According to `man bash`:

> ```
> PROMPT_COMMAND
>     If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
> ```

With that, every time bash writes the prompt it will execute the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which will update the `PS1` value before bash writes it, so it'll have the latest value at the time it is written.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `upower`. And all Shells support looping so you can do something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Loop trough all batteries
for battery in /sys/class/power_supply/BAT?
do
    # Get capacity of battery
    capacity=$(cat "$battery"/capacity) || exit

    # Get status of battery
    status=$(cat "$battery"/status)

    # Print capacity and status
    echo "$capacity" \| "$status"
done
```

Explanation: Your battery information is stored in `/sys/class/power_supply/` individual batteries are named `BAT` and some number i.e. `BAT0, BAT1, ...`. Since everything on linux is a file you can simply cat out the content of `BAT0/status` and `BAT0/capacity` to get the info you want, and then print it with `echo`. If you have some more questions please ask!

Comment: This is informative, but the OP didn't ask about alternatives to `upower`.

Comment: I know but that doesn't change the fact that this is approach is lot easier, faster and over all better, for what OP is trying to do